# Facing Problem in UITabar Item deselect

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having some problems with uitabbaritem.
I have created uitabbaritem programmatically.
And what I want is by default none of the tabbaritems should be selected.
Here is some of the code which I used.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

// Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:landingController,aboutUsController, featuresController,faqController, contactUsController, nil]];
```

Any one having idea How can I get rid of it???
Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid you are attempting to contradict to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines by making a standard control behave in a totally non-standard way.

Comment: I m Sorry. I am new to Iphone application,but I didnt get you. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: All I need is to create a landing page screen(i.e after login screen) with tab bar items. But problem I am facing it is loading the first tab bar items by default instead of landing screen.

Comment: Note; your current accept-rate is 25% which is very low - make sure your accept answers that answer your query. To accept an answer, click on the gray checkmark close to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing a page that shall not be part of the regular navigation, use `[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]` like this example:

Somewhere within your app-delegate, right after adding your tabBarController to the active view/window;

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:landingController animated:NO];
```

Comment: I have not implemented in delegate.So I am not sure it will work.I think my application is very complicated.What I want is when new view comes, in that view by default none of the tababritems should be selected.By default its coming setSelectedIndex = 0.That I want to change so that none of the tabbaritems selected.